# Lightweight Access Point - trunk port or not

Tags: ap

While learning wireless for cisco, I came across two seemingly contradictory (at least to me) claims regarding LWAPS and whether they should be trunked or not.

In the OCG for the CCNA:

> *Also, notice how the AP is known by only a single IP address: 10.10.10.10. Because the AP sits on the access layer where its CAPWAP tunnels terminate, it can use one IP address for both management and
> tunneling. No trunk link is needed because all of the VLANs it
> supports are encapsulated and tunneled as Layer 3 IP packets, rather
> than individual Layer 2 VLANs.*

In CCNAv7.0 lab titled "Configure a WPA2 Enterprise WLAN on the WLC" it states:

> *Each WLAN requires a virtual interface on the WLC. These interfaces are known as dynamic interfaces. The virtual interface is assigned a
> VLAN ID and traffic that uses the interface will be tagged as VLAN
> traffic. This is why connections between the APs, the WLC, and the
> router are over trunk ports.*

And if the first statement is true, isn't the WLC a part of the CAPWAP tunnel system as well, why is a trunk port deemed necessary to carry multiple WLANs from that side but not the AP side?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think you've found a typo. The APs tunnel everything to the WLC. The WLC must have VLAN interfaces in order to forward traffic into those networks. In general, so does the router. ('tho it could have physical interfaces.) I don't think LWAPs can even be configured to locally forward traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Ricky. Yeah, my picture is coming together now, WLC needs trunks to connect to the rest of the network in that VLAN but the LWAP doesn't because it is tunneled with CAPWAP. But I think FlexConnect does local switching of traffic without WLC so I presume you might need to trunk it for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WLC requires a trunk port to forward 802.1Q tagged frames onto the wired network after these frames have been de-encapsulated from the CAPWAP tunnel coming from the LWAPP.

To answer your question regarding FlexConnect in another comment, yes a FlexConnect LWAPP requires the connected switchport to be configured as a trunk. This is because the LWAPP applies 802.1Q tags to the FlexConnect traffic before forwarding to the switch, the trunk port is required to carry these tags.